# Selenium4 Dynamic Grid setup using different VM's

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, automation-testing, selenium-java

In the official documentation of selenium docker setup, I see a config.toml file which contains below info

```
[docker]
# Configs have a mapping between the Docker image to use and the capabilities that need to be matched to
# start a container with the given image.
configs = [
    "selenium/standalone-firefox:4.3.0-20220706", "{\"browserName\": \"firefox\"}",
    "selenium/standalone-chrome:4.3.0-20220706", "{\"browserName\": \"chrome\"}",
    "selenium/standalone-edge:4.3.0-20220706", "{\"browserName\": \"MicrosoftEdge\"}"
    ]

# URL for connecting to the docker daemon
# Most simple approach, leave it as http://127.0.0.1:2375, and mount /var/run/docker.sock.
# 127.0.0.1 is used because interally the container uses socat when /var/run/docker.sock is mounted 
# If var/run/docker.sock is not mounted: 
# Windows: make sure Docker Desktop exposes the daemon via tcp, and use http://host.docker.internal:2375.
# macOS: install socat and run the following command, socat -4 TCP-LISTEN:2375,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock,
# then use http://host.docker.internal:2375.
# Linux: varies from machine to machine, please mount /var/run/docker.sock. If this does not work, please create an issue.
url = "http://127.0.0.1:2375"
# Docker image used for video recording
video-image = "selenium/video:ffmpeg-4.3.1-20220706"

# Uncomment the following section if you are running the node on a separate VM
# Fill out the placeholders with appropriate values
[server]
host = <ip-from-node-machine>
port = <port-from-node-machine>
```

What does the bottom two parameters represent **host and port**?

FYI- I am planning to run the hub container in one VM and nodes containers in another VM's.
Correct me if I am wrong, I am guessing config.toml file should be present in the VM's where we would be running the nodes

**So, for host= should we need to give Ip of where hub is up and running?
and
for port= where we get the port number?**
Expecting answers ASAP, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us a reference to that doc?

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **host** and **port** values are the details of where your **Hub** is running. **Port** number is **4444** if your hub is running on the default port.